# How to get the Minimum and Maximum temperatures from WeatherKit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, temperature, weatherkit

I am trying to get the Minimum and Maximum Temperatures from Apple's WeatherKit to make a complication in my Weather app but Apple's Developer Documentation does not show how to get the value and nobody has asked this question before.

Here is the code I tried but didn't work:

```swift
Text("L: \(weather.currentWeather.lowTemperature) H: \(weather.currentWeather.highTemperature)")
// Text("L: \(Minimum Temperature) H: \(Maximum Temperature)")
```

Here is what I expected(i hardcoded this):[image: hardcoded image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it with `DayWeather`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/weatherkit/dayweather

```
var highTemperature: Measurement<UnitTemperature>
var lowTemperature: Measurement<UnitTemperature>
```

You can get it with `.daily`

```
let daily = try await service.weather(for: newYork, including: .daily)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/weatherkit/weatherquery

Answer (score -1):

try using [DayWeather]

updated code will be:
Text("L: (weather.dailyForecase[0].lowTemperature) H: (weather.dailyForecast[0].highTemperature)")

here [0] is the first index of the array items in DayWeather